# java -change boolean to yes no

Tags: java, swing, boolean

I have a boolean array and need them displayed to the user later, as opposed to showing true or false I'd like to display yes or no. Could someone please help me on this?

```
    public static boolean[] seen (boolean[] birds)
    {   String quit = "100";
        String ans = "";
        while(!ans.equals(quit))
        {   ans=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Which bird are you reporting? \n   1) Blue Tit\n   2) Blackbird\n   3) Robin\n   4) Wren\n   5) Greenfinch");
            if (ans.equals("1"))
            {   birds[0]=true;
            }
            else if (ans.equals("2"))
            {   birds[1]=true;
            }
            else if (ans.equals("3"))
            {   birds[2]=true;
            }
            else if (ans.equals("4"))
            {   birds[3]=true;
            }
            else if (ans.equals("5"))
            {   birds[4]=true;
            }
        }
        return birds;   
    }
public static void display(boolean[] newbirds)
    {   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"newbirds[0]+" "+newbirds[1]+" "+newbirds[2]+" "+newbirds[3]+" "+ newbirds[4]+"");
    }
}
```

I would like the arrays newbirds[i] displayed as yes or no format, could someone help?

Comment: For '1 of a group' it would be better to use radio buttons in a button group, or a single selection list, or a combo box or a spinner or..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be used to loop over the array and print "yes " or "no " :

```
            boolean[] newbirds = {false, true, true};
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(boolean bird : newbirds){
                sb.append(bird? "yes " : "no "); 
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 6):

You could define a method for it somewhat like this

```
public String booleanToString(boolean b) {
    return b ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

What I used above is called a ternary operator.
It works like this:

```
boolean (expression) ? actionIfTrue : actionIfFalse
```

1st part I think is quite easy. It is just any expression or variable or any thing that is or evaluates to a boolean. For example `a == b` or `true`.

2nd part is `actionIfTrue` it is called only when expression is `true`.
3rd part is `actionIfFalse` it is called only when expression is `false`.

It works like a shortened `if`. The above in `if` statement would look like this:

```
if (b)
    return "yes";
else
    return "no";
```

Use it like this:

```
boolean a = false;
boolean b = !a;
// etc

someMethod( booleanToString(a) + " xyz " + booleanToString(b) );
```

Comment: The next thing to add to that would be a `StringBuilder` to create the string bit by bit and a loop to add to the string builder (calling the `booleanToString` for each array value).  Much more elegant and adaptable (for example, for different array sizes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ApacheCommons

from String to boolean

```
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject(string)
```

from boolean to string

```
BooleanUtils.toString(boolVal,"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Use ternary operator :

    String yesOrNo = condition?result1:result2
   // so if condition is true the returned value will be result1 else it will be result2. 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, newbirds[0]?"Yes":"No"+" "+newbirds[1]?"Yes":"No"+" "+newbirds[2]?"Yes":"No"+" "+newbirds[3]?"Yes":"No"+" "+ newbirds[4]?"Yes":"No");

  //  or you can make a method to get the value.

    String yesOrNo(boolean b){
       return b?"Yes":"No";
    }

    //use it like
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,yesOrNo(newbirds[index]));
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it provides no context to explain the recommended changes. Edit your answer to include an explanation of what you have written.

Comment: Please write comments after `//` so they don't mix up when reading.